# Adding an Additional Power Source for the LED Strip Connected to the Television

Tags: power-supply, led-strip, tv

I want to turn on a long LED strip when the TV is turned on. I thought of doing this using the TV's USB port. The problem is that the voltage from the TV's USB port is very low and cannot support such a long LED strip.
So, I want to add a power supply to this. The question is, how do I make this system work? So that when the TV turns on, it triggers the power supply, which then turns on the LEDs

Thanks!

[image: Diagram]

Comment: So the TV is always plugged in and you turn it on with the remote controller?

Comment: If the USB port is always active, then you cannot detect from the USB port when to turn LEDs on or off. You need to first verify how it works to know if you can do it. Then, how to do it is the next question.